# Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types named "Page"

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I created a GraphQL Page function. However, when I try to reuse it, I got error

> Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types
>   named "Page"

I know I can change `Page` to two same functions and name them to `JobsPage` and `PrintsPage`.

However, is there an easy way to reuse it? Thanks

```
function Page(itemType) {
  return new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Page',
    fields: () => ({
      totalCount: { type: GraphQLInt },
      edges: { type: new GraphQLList(Edge(itemType)) },
      pageInfo: { type: PageInfo }
    })
  });
}


const PrinterType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Printer',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },

    jobs: {
      type: Page(JobType),     // here I use Page first time
      args: {
        first: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        },
        after: {
          type: GraphQLString
        }
      },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        const { id } = parentValue;
        const { first, after } = args;

        return getPageJobs({ id, first, after });
      }
    },

    prints: {
      type: Page(PrintType),   // here I use Page again
      args: {
        first: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        },
        after: {
          type: GraphQLString
        }
      },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        const { id } = parentValue;
        const { first, after } = args;

        return getPagePrints({ id, first, after });
      }
    },
  })
});
```

Comment: FWIW, if your schema includes connections or other features used by Relay, Relay actually has a library that includes different utilities to implement those features in a GraphQL.js server: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed it is just a pure function, I can pass a second value...

Here is one solution.

```
function Page(itemType, name) {
  return new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: `${name}Page`,
    fields: () => ({
      totalCount: { type: GraphQLInt },
      edges: { type: new GraphQLList(Edge(itemType, name)) },
      pageInfo: { type: PageInfo }
    })
  });
}


const PrinterType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Printer',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },

    jobs: {
      type: Page(JobType, 'Jobs'),     // here I use Page first time
      args: {
        first: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        },
        after: {
          type: GraphQLString
        }
      },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        const { id } = parentValue;
        const { first, after } = args;

        return getPageJobs({ id, first, after });
      }
    },

    prints: {
      type: Page(PrintType, 'Prints'),   // here I use Page again
      args: {
        first: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        },
        after: {
          type: GraphQLString
        }
      },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        const { id } = parentValue;
        const { first, after } = args;

        return getPagePrints({ id, first, after });
      }
    },
  })
});
```